# Using MatLab for Image Steganography

Tags: matlab, image-processing, octave, steganography

I am using octave to decrypt an Image. I have to recover the image that is hidden inside the Carrier image. The code I have is only working if the target image is in black and white, how can i adjust it so it will also work in color.

```
 I2 = imread('c:/df/output/stegoFlowers.png');

 output_stream="";
 data_size_s="";     %In bytes and as a string  

 k=1;
 for i=1:rows(I2)
    for j=1:columns(I2)
     if (k<18) s=dec2bin(double(I2(i,j,1)),8); data_size_s=strcat(data_size_s,s(8)); k++; endif
     if (k<18) s=dec2bin(double(I2(i,j,2)),8); data_size_s=strcat(data_size_s,s(8));    k++; endif
     if (k<18) s=dec2bin(double(I2(i,j,3)),8); data_size_s=strcat(data_size_s,s(8));   k++; endif
 end
end

%We pass the size of the target image from string to integer
target_rows=uint32(bin2dec(substr(data_size_s, 1,8)));   
target_columns=uint32(bin2dec(substr(data_size_s,9,8))); 
data_size_int=target_rows*target_columns;  % Data Size in bytes as integer


%We read the output_stream from the stego image
total_data_size=(8*data_size_int)+16;    % Total length of the output stream (header +target data)

k=1;
for i=1:rows(I2)
  for j=1:columns(I2)
  if (k<=(total_data_size)) s=dec2bin(double(I2(i,j,1)),8); output_stream=strcat(output_stream,s(8)); k++; endif
  if (k<=(total_data_size)) s=dec2bin(double(I2(i,j,2)),8); output_stream=strcat(output_stream,s(8)); k++; endif
  if (k<=(total_data_size)) s=dec2bin(double(I2(i,j,3)),8); output_stream=strcat(output_stream,s(8)); k++; endif
  end
end


I3_rows=uint32(bin2dec(substr(output_stream,1,8)));
I3_columns=uint32(bin2dec(substr(output_stream,9,8)));
k=17;

I3=uint8(zeros(I3_rows,I3_columns,3));     
total_data_size=(8*data_size_int)+16;
for i=1:I3_rows
  for j=1:I3_columns
   if (k<=total_data_size) I3(i,j,1)=uint8(bin2dec(substr(output_stream,k,8))); k=k+8; endif
     if (k<=total_data_size) I3(i,j,2)=uint8(bin2dec(substr(output_stream,k,8))); k=k+8; endif
    if (k<=total_data_size) I3(i,j,3)=uint8(bin2dec(substr(output_stream,k,8))); k=k+8; endif


  end
end

 %We show the hidden image.
 imshow(I3);
```

Comment: By black and white, do you mean grayscale?

Comment: this code only works if the target image is black and white, not color

Comment: Eh, we were talking about the same thing. Anyway, a color image has 3 planes for each R, G and B component. A black and white image has only one plane. It seems what you need to do is hide all three color planes and for that you'll need 3 times the space.